# Integral of a gaussian function depending on an angle

Tags: definite-integrals

Suppose we have the following function:
$$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2})$$
and suppose the variable $x$ is depending on an angle $\alpha$:
$$x=sin(\alpha)$$
Is it possible to give an analytic expression of the integral
$\Phi(\alpha)$?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with the following consideration:
$$
   x^2=\sin^2(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2\alpha))
$$
and so the function becomes
$$
  \Phi(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{4\sigma^2}(1-\cos(2\alpha))}.
$$
Then you note that
$$
   e^{z\cos\theta}=I_0(z)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n(z)\cos(n\theta)
$$
being in your case $I_n(z)$ modified Bessel funtions, $z=-\frac{1}{4\sigma^2}$ and $\theta=2\alpha$. Finally, the integral can be evaluated provided it is done on a finite interval.